# How do I rotate a bone without effecting the connected bones?

Tags: animation, rigging

I've been looking for answers to this problem, but I'm too much of a newbie with rigging to understand some of your answers.

So here's the thing: I'm trying to modelize and animate steelix:

[image: Yeah, this guy]
Considering his snake-like shape, he's not so hard to rig and animate, and this is what I made:

[image]
But here's the problem: Steelix's spiked boulders can rotate on themselves, and with this rigging, whenever I rotate a bone, the whole body parts connected to this bone also rotates.

What should I do to make that the boulders rotate only on themselves?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go into Bone Edit Mode of the Armature. <kbd>Tab</kbd>
2. Select the *spiked_boulder* bone and duplicate it. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>
   For further convenience, let's scale this bone down, so we can discern it later on. Let's name it *spiked_boulder_rotation*.
3. Parent *spiked_boulder_rotation* to *spiked_boulder*. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>
4. Assign/Parent the spiked boulder mesh to the *spiked_boulder_rotation* bone.

Now you can animate the movement of the spine in a standard fashion. The child *spiked_boulder_rotation* will rotate along its parent moving the geometry. Now animated the Y Rotation of the *spiked_boulder_rotation* if you want to additionally rotate the spike geo.

Comment: Nice! Thanks Leander! I think I'll upload the animation and post the link here soon if I manage to pull it off quickly.